# Error reading Struct in python on Raspberry pi 3b+ sent from Arduino using NRF24L01+

Tags: python, struct, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I've been struggling to send sensor values from arduino to raspberry pi 3b+. I'm using NRF24L01+ module to communicate. I'm trying to send accelerometer values (double type) from arduino to raspberry pi.
A part of Arduino code that's sending values:

```
typedef struct {
  double rollx;
  double pitchy;
}myStruct;

myStruct duomenys;

  duomenys.rollx = kalAngleX;
  duomenys.pitchy = kalAngleY;
  radio.write(&duomenys,sizeof(duomenys));

  Serial.print("Roll: ");
  Serial.println(duomenys.rollx);
  Serial.print("Pitch: ");
  Serial.println(duomenys.pitchy);
  Serial.print("\t");
```

Here's the arduino serial monitor output:

```
Pitch: -12.98
    Roll: 89.85
Pitch: -12.97
    Roll: 89.85
Pitch: -12.96
    Roll: 89.86
```

However on the raspberry side, I'm not able to Unpack the received structure (Note: I'm pretty new to python). What I've tried is:

```
while True:

    while not radio.available(0):
      ##  print("Nepareina")
        time.sleep(1)

    duomenys = []

    radio.read(duomenys, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    data = struct.unpack('ff',duomenys)
    rollx = data [0]
    pitchy = data[1]
    print(rollx)
    print("                              ")
    print(pitchy)
```

When compiling this code, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/NRF24L01/receiveArduino.py", line 41, in <module>
    data = struct.unpack('ff',duomenys)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

If I change the line

```
data = struct.unpack('ff',duomenys)
```

to

```
data = struct.unpack('ff',bytes(duomenys))
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/NRF24L01/receiveArduino.py", line 41, in <module>
    data = struct.unpack('ff',bytes(duomenys))
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to read the received struct in python, feel free to share.

EDIT: Updated the arduino serial monitor output. Previously had posted the wrong output.

EDIT: This is the NRF24L01library I'm using.
https://github.com/matmany/lib_nrf24

Comment: Have you checked the value of `duomenys`?

Comment: If you're talking about the output on the arduino side, my bad there, got the ouput from the other version of the code (which is **int** type not **double**).

Comment: I was just asking if the contents of `duomenys` are what you expect. Hint: Use a debugger or print it, if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, they are what I was expecting. The problem here is on the raspberry side. I am not able to Unpack the values of `duomenys` in python.

Comment: can you please print out the contents of `duomenys` on the python side.
It will be much easier to help if we can see it.

Comment: On the python side I just created a blank list `duomenys = []` thinking that I'll be able to store the received struct in there. But apparently I was wrong, since I'm not able to unpack the struct this way.

Comment: After leaving only `duomenys = []
    radio.read(duomenys, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print(duomenys)` the output is blank.

Comment: Also tested by sending a single string. Everything worked as expected. So everything is alright with the communication between the modules. Not sure why the `duomenys` list is blank when sending the struct.

Comment: pls try `result = radio.read(duomenys, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())`
and print then the contents of `result`

You might also just post the declaration of `radio.read` or if it is from a library post its documentation. It might be, that you don't call it as expected.

Comment: The output of `result` is `1`. I am using a lib_nrf24 library for the module. Will add the library file on the post.

Comment: @AiridasJeznas Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I do not know if you solved it or not. I was having the same issue and I managed to solve it like this:

Instead of declaring `duomenys = []` ... try `duomenys = bytearray(nbBytesData)`, where nbBytesData should be the number of bytes you are expecting (I'm assuming 8 bytes)

Then the `data = struct.unpack('ff',duomenys)` should work.